# Assign parameters with strong parameters and nested models in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-activerecord, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

it's the first time that i make a question here. i tried many answers yet, but none have solved my problem.(Sorry for my english, i'm working to improve).

Okai, the issue is the following: I'm doing a e-shop and it have products. A product must have a category, but not necessarily a subcategory. The idea is that only creating a product, including the category and subcategory names as parameters, rails must create automatically the entries for the category and subcategory tables.

The problem is when i create a product with the form. When i do this, in the console i see: "Unpermitted parameters: category, subcategory"

This are the three models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :subcategory
    has_one :category, through: :subcategory

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :category, :subcategory
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    has_many :subcategories

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :subcategories
end

class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :category
end
```

The controller relevant part:

```
def create
    @titulo = "Catálogo Online"
    @product = Product.create(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @product.save
            format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Producto creado.' }
        else
            format.html { render :new }
        end
    end
end

...

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :price, :stock, :code, category_attributes: [:id, :category, :product_id ], subcategory_attributes: [:id, :subcategory, :category_id, :product_id ])
end
```

And the form

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :category %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :subcategory %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :subcategory %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :code %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :code %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :stock %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :stock %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Please, I been three days with this problem. i don't know what to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, I would say, is that you are using a text_field input for category and sub_category. In order for this to work, you should use a select field and then provide another way in the UI to create categories and sub_categories.

Replacing f.text_field :subcategory with (and removing the :category option because your data model will not allow this) something like...

```
<%= f.collection_select :subcategory_id, Subcategory.all, :id, :name, { selected: @product.subcategory_id } %>
```

…should enable you to assign a product to a subcategory.

Also, your data model looks incorrect here. The product needs to belong to the subcategory, not the other way round.

Comment: Thanks. That works and is a improve to the form very useful, but it's not exactly what i want. The idea is that the same form can create the entries for all tables. It's that possible? Respect to the data model: Originally i had it of the way that you say, but i discarded it because i realized that the logic to do what i want was more complicated. It's better the other data model? Why?. I'm beginner in this, so all the help is welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think you have any option but to take another look at your data model. Yes. It's complicated having inline creation of related models! Perhaps start by doing something simple (assigning already created categories) and then once you have that working, look at how to allow the user to create more categories. I think your subcategories setup is going to complicate things too!